# How do I add a tooltip to a dynamically created table row in javascript?

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I want to add a tool-tip for each of the table rows that are being created in a `HTML` table:

```
document.getElementById("insert").addEventListener("click",function(){
    table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

    //add a tooltip for each row
})
```

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use setAttribute methods.

```
document.getElementById("insert").addEventListener("click",function(){
    //add a tooltip for each row
var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
      newRow.setAttribute("title", "tooltip text");
})
```